# How to reattach objects from Asp.Net MVC 4 to Fluent NHibernate

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jquery, nhibernate

I'm writing a web app, using asp.net MVC with Razor views, where data to and from the server is handled by ajax and mapped to the UI using KnockoutJs.

My model is hierarchical and has lists of child objects. Now here's the catch:

When I have edited the main object (that is already in the database) - changed some properties, added a child, etc. - how should I go about updating it in NHibernate?

In a windows app the main object exists in the NHibernate session and can be updated easily. In my webapp I desrialize JSON into a "new" object, that then needs to be reattached to NHibernate session. Actually this deserialization is done by the modelbinder.

Is there a smart way of doing this? I tried Merge, but it won't work with added children.

My current solution, is to handle each change to the model seperately, ie. when I add a child, I update through NHibernate (load mainmodel by id, add the child to the model and hit update), when I update some simple property I use merge. I just don't think this solution is very elegant.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried a simple `nhibernateSession.SaveOrUpdate(myNewObject);` or `nhibernateSession.Update(myNewObject);` ?

Comment: Yes. Hibernate recognises the id of the object, and rejects it.

Comment: To clarify: the object I'm trying to save has no reference in the Hibernate session, as it is created by MVC Modelbinder. The object is Equals the one i the session, but not ReferenceEquals.

Comment: thx for the follow-up. Have you tried evicting ( `nhSession.Evict(...)` the existing object from the session before trying to SaveOrUpdate the poco ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's definitely confusing when you move from a stateful to a stateless world. You've got the pattern just about right though, in your action method:

1. Load the object from the database
2. Make changes to it based on the view model
3. Flush the session/commit the transaction

You do not need to call Update or SaveOrUpdate if the object is being tracked in a session, and you;re using Merge incorrectly. Typically the only persistence method you need to call is Save to make a new object persistent.

Comment: So: load from DB, and map all changes from the model created by MVC to the model loaded from the DB?

Comment: Can i add new child objects to an existing model without Update?

Comment: Yes, load from db, update model, commit transaction. You can add new child objects without calling update due to the default cascade mode. Many-to-many relationships are different, the new object must be Saved first.

Comment: I was hoping for at more elegant solution, than simple mapping. Of course there's things like automapper, but they tend to get quite complex, when it needs to be aware of the hibernate session.

Maybe a custom modelbinder, that is aware of the hibernate session, would make a more elegant solution?

Comment: I tend to use a simple `ModelCopier` and not auto mapper I found on MVC futures. https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=mvcfutures+modelcopier&oq=mvcfutures+modelcopier&aqs=chrome..69i57.5111j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8